# Expand table by merging additional variables as columns

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that looks like this but with  several more binary outcome variables:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long ID byte(Region Type Tier Secure Offshore Highland)
120034 12 1 2 1 0 1
120035 12 1 2 1 0 1
120036 12 1 2 1 0 1
120037 12 1 2 1 0 1
120038 41 1 2 1 0 0
120039 41 2 2 1 1 0
120040 41 2 1 0 1 0
120041 41 2 1 0 1 0
120042 41 2 1 0 1 0
120043 41 2 1 0 0 .
120044 65 2 1 0 0 .
120045 65 3 1 0 0 0
120046 65 3 1 1 0 0
120047 65 3 2 1 1 0
120048 65 3 2 1 0 0
120049 65 3 2 . 1 1
120050 25 3 2 . 1 1
120051 25 5 2 . 1 1
120052 25 5 1 . 0 1
120053 25 5 2 . 0 .
120054 25 5 2 0 0 .
120055 25 5 1 0 . 0
120056 25 5 1 0 . 0
120057 95 7 1 0 1 0
120058 95 7 1 0 1 0
120059 95 7 1 1 1 0
120060 95 7 2 1 0 1
120061 95 7 2 1 0 1
120062 59 7 2 1 0 1
120063 95 8 2 0 . 1
120064 59 8 1 0 . 1
120065 59 8 1 0 . 0
120066 59 8 1 1 . 0
120067 59 8 1 1 1 0
120068 59 8 2 1 1 0
120069 40 9 2 1 1 1
120070 40 9 2 1 0 1
120071 40 9 2 1 0 1
120072 40 9 1 0 0 1
end
```

I am creating a table with the *community-contributed* command `tabout`:

```
foreach v of var Secure Offshore Highland{
    tabout Region Type Tier `v' using `v'.docx ///
    , replace ///
    style(docx) font(bold) c(freq row) ///
    f(1) layout(cb) landscape nlab(Obs) paper(A4)
    }
```

It has both row frequencies, percentages and the totals.

However, I did not need all this information so i modified my code as follows:

```
foreach v of var Secure Offshore Highland{
    tabout Region Type Tier `v' using `v'.docx ///
    , replace ///
    style(docx) font(bold) c(freq row) ///
    f(1) layout(cb) h3(nil) h2(nil) dropc(2 3 4 5 7) landscape nlab(Obs) paper(A4)
    }
```

This produces what I need but both versions of my code create three individual tables for each outcome variables. I have to manually make one table combining the three tables keeping the left-most column, the % of "1" column and the right-most column showing the row-total.

Can anyone help me out here regarding:

1. Merging all the tables in one go, keeping the exploratory variable labels on the left-most and the rowtotal on the right-most column.
2. Instead of deleting the columns except % of "1"s, I only want to have the desired column. Deleting columns seem so crude and dangerous.
3. Can i get this same output in Excel through "putexcel"? I tried following the wonderfully written blog by Chuck Huber. But I cannot figure out the "merging" part.

I came this far due to lots and lots of studying, especially Ian Watson's "User Guide for `tabout` Version 3" and Nicholas Cox's "How to face lists with fortitude".

Cross-posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1520678-expand-2x2-table-by-merging-additional-variables-as-columns-with-tabout-or-putexcel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this readily with `tabout` -- custom tables require custom programming.

My advice is to create a matrix with whatever values you need and then use the (also) *community-contributed* command `esttab` to tabulate and export everything.

That said, what you want requires *a lot* of work but here is a simplified example based on your data:

```
matrix N = J(1, 2, .)

local i 0
foreach v in Region Type Tier {
    local i = `i' + 1
    tabulate `v' Secure, matcell(A`i') 
    matrix arowsum = J(1, rowsof(A`i'), 1) * A`i'
    matrix A`i' = A`i' \ arowsum
    if `i' > 1 local N \ N
    matrix m1a = (nullmat(m1a) `N' \ A`i')
}

local i 0
foreach v in Region Type Tier {
    local i = `i' + 1
    tabulate `v' Offshore, matcell(B`i') 
    matrix browsum = J(1, rowsof(B`i'), 1) * B`i'
    matrix B`i' = B`i' \ browsum
    if `i' > 1 local N \ N
    matrix m2a = (nullmat(m2a) `N' \ B`i')
}

local i 0
foreach v in Region Type Tier {
    local i = `i' + 1
    tabulate `v' Highland, matcell(C`i') 
    matrix crowsum = J(1, rowsof(C`i'), 1) * C`i'
    matrix C`i' = C`i' \ crowsum
    if `i' > 1 local N \ N
    matrix m3a = (nullmat(m3a) `N' \ C`i')
}

matrix m1b = m1a * J(colsof(m1a), 1, 1)
matrix m2b = m2a * J(colsof(m2a), 1, 1)
matrix m3b = m3a * J(colsof(m3a), 1, 1)

matrix M1 = m1a, m1b 
matrix M2 = m2a, m2b
matrix M3 = m3a, m3b

matrix K = J(1, 3, .)
matrix M = M1 \ K \ M2 \ K \ M3
```

You can then use `esttab` to export the results in Excel or Word:

```
esttab matrix(M)

---------------------------------------------------
                        M                          
                       c1           c2           c1
---------------------------------------------------
r1                      0            4            4
r2                      3            0            3
r3                      1            3            4
r4                      4            2            6
r5                      2            4            6
r6                      2            3            5
r7                      3            3            6
r1                     15           19           34
r1                      .            .            .
r1                      0            5            5
r2                      5            1            6
r3                      1            3            4
r4                      3            0            3
r5                      2            4            6
r6                      3            3            6
r7                      1            3            4
r1                     15           19           34
r1                      .            .            .
r1                     13            4           17
r2                      2           15           17
r1                     15           19           34
r1                      .            .            .
r1                      .            .            .
r1                      4            0            4
r2                      3            2            5
r3                      3            1            4
r4                      2            4            6
r5                      1            2            3
r6                      4            2            6
r7                      2            3            5
r1                     19           14           33
r1                      .            .            .
r1                      5            0            5
r2                      2            4            6
r3                      3            3            6
r4                      3            1            4
r5                      3            3            6
r6                      0            2            2
r7                      3            1            4
r1                     19           14           33
r1                      .            .            .
r1                      6            7           13
r2                     13            7           20
r1                     19           14           33
r1                      .            .            .
r1                      .            .            .
r1                      0            4            4
r2                      2            3            5
r3                      0            4            4
r4                      5            0            5
r5                      4            2            6
r6                      4            1            5
r7                      3            3            6
r1                     18           17           35
r1                      .            .            .
r1                      1            4            5
r2                      4            0            4
r3                      4            2            6
r4                      2            2            4
r5                      3            3            6
r6                      4            2            6
r7                      0            4            4
r1                     18           17           35
r1                      .            .            .
r1                     13            3           16
r2                      5           14           19
r1                     18           17           35
---------------------------------------------------
```

You will have to generate the rest of the elements you want separately (including column and row names etc.) but the idea is the same. You will also have to play with the options in `esttab` to fine tune the desired final outcome.

Note that the above can be written more efficiently but I have kept everything separate in this answer so you can understand it.

---

**EDIT:**

If you are working with matrices as above you can also use `putexcel` easily:

```
putexcel A1 = matrix(M)
```